# Как записать данные с JSON в массив?

Tags: json, swift

Получать данные я научился, а потом попробовал воспользоваться генератором на jsoncafe.com в SwiftyJSON, но увы

```
class RootClass : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var byTeacher : String!
    var disc : String!
    var duration : String!
    var group : String!
    var status : String!
    var timeOut : String!
    var user : String!

    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed json values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        byTeacher = json["by_teacher"].stringValue
        disc = json["disc"].stringValue
        duration = json["duration"].stringValue
        group = json["group"].stringValue
        status = json["status"].stringValue
        timeOut = json["time_out"].stringValue
        user = json["user"].stringValue
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
    {
        var dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if byTeacher != nil{
            dictionary["by_teacher"] = byTeacher
        }
        if disc != nil{
            dictionary["disc"] = disc
        }
        if duration != nil{
            dictionary["duration"] = duration
        }
        if group != nil{
            dictionary["group"] = group
        }
        if status != nil{
            dictionary["status"] = status
        }
        if timeOut != nil{
            dictionary["time_out"] = timeOut
        }
        if user != nil{
            dictionary["user"] = user
        }
        return dictionary
    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required initializer.
    * Fills the data from the passed decoder
    */
    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        byTeacher = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "by_teacher") as? String
        disc = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "disc") as? String
        duration = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "duration") as? String
        group = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "group") as? String
        status = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "status") as? String
        timeOut = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "time_out") as? String
        user = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "user") as? String
    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required method.
    * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
    */
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        if byTeacher != nil{
            aCoder.encode(byTeacher, forKey: "by_teacher")
        }
        if disc != nil{
            aCoder.encode(disc, forKey: "disc")
        }
        if duration != nil{
            aCoder.encode(duration, forKey: "duration")
        }
        if group != nil{
            aCoder.encode(group, forKey: "group")
        }
        if status != nil{
            aCoder.encode(status, forKey: "status")
        }
        if timeOut != nil{
            aCoder.encode(timeOut, forKey: "time_out")
        }
        if user != nil{
            aCoder.encode(user, forKey: "user")
        }

    }

}


        AF.request(url, method: .get).responseData { [self] response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                var json = JSON(response.value!)
                print(json)
                let user = RootClass(fromJson: json)
                print(user.group)
            case .failure(_):
                print("Ошибка при запросе данных \(String(describing: response.error))")
                return
            }
        }
```

Вот текст самого JSON

```
[
  {
    "duration" : "62",
    "status" : "IN",
    "time_out" : "23:51:18",
    "user" : "Зенковский Александр Михайлович",
    "group" : "КТбо2-10",
    "by_teacher" : "0",
    "disc" : "лек_Высшая_математика"
  },
  {
    "duration" : "46",
    "status" : "OUT",
    "time_out" : "15:56:35",
    "user" : "Зенковский Александр Михайлович",
    "group" : "КТбо2-10",
    "by_teacher" : "0",
    "disc" : "лек_Высшая_математика"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас JSON состоит из массива json, поэтому вы должны обрабатывать его как массив. В let user = RootClass(fromJson: json) вы пытаетесь передать массив,  вместо одного значения из массива. Попробуйте, например, так: let user = RootClass(fromJson: json[0])